# Issue with not entering a loop in c

Tags: c, loops

The code compiles however where my while loop should run until an odd number is inputted it only runs through once no matter whatever is added in there.  From what I understand I should be able to use it like this however I cannot seem to figure it out what-so-ever

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>


//variables
bool flag = false;
int input = 0;
//function protoypes
void  get_input(void);
bool  is_valid(int);


int main(){
  get_input();


  return 0;
}
void get_input(){
  while(flag == false){
    printf("please enter an odd number betwen 1 and 9\n");
    scanf("%d", &input);
    if(is_valid){
      flag = true;
    }else{
      flag = false;
    }

  }



}
bool is_valid(int number){
  if(number == 1 || number == 3 || number == 5 || number == 7 || number == 9){
    return true;
  }else{
    return false;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You calling is_valid function in wrong way.
Try :

```
if(is_valid(input)) {
    //code
} ....
```

Comment: Thanks I couldn't figure it out.  I'm fairly new to C and usually the java IDEs I've used would've thrown a fit.  I've been quite spoiled with it.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you are not calling your function. (line `is_valid` should be `is_valid(number)`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>


//variables
bool flag = false;
int input = 0;
//function protoypes
void  get_input(void);
bool  is_valid(int);


int main(){
  get_input();


  return 0;
}
void get_input(){
  while(flag == false){
    printf("please enter an odd number betwen 1 and 9\n");
    scanf("%d", &input);
    if(is_valid(input)){
      flag = true;
    }else{
      flag = false;
    }

  }



}
bool is_valid(int number){
  if(number == 1 || number == 3 || number == 5 || number == 7 || number == 9){
    return true;
  }else{
    return false;
  }
}
```

also, you can remove the function entirely by doing a modulo operation, so your `is_valid` will be:

```
    if(input <= 9 && input >= 1 && input % 2 != 0){
      flag = true;
    }else{
      flag = false;
    }
```

It can even be further simplified to:

```
    flag = (input <= 9 && input >= 1 && input % 2 != 0);
```

So your whole code can be:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

//variables
bool flag = false;
int input = 0;
//function protoypes
void  get_input(void);
int main(){
  get_input();
  return 0;
}
void get_input(){
  while(flag == false){
    printf("please enter an odd number betwen 1 and 9\n");
    scanf("%d", &input);
    flag = (input <= 9 && input >= 1 && input % 2 != 0);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here

```
if(is_valid)
```

it should be

```
if(is_valid(input))
```

You did not pass `input` to the function `is_valid()`. That is what had been causing the problem.

Hope this solves your problem   :)

Answer (score 0):

This line is the problem:

```
if(is_valid){
```

Since `is_valid` is a function, the expression `is_valid`, without parentheses, evaluates as the *address* of the function rather than the *result* of calling said function.

Since the address of the function will never be `NULL` or `0`, it will always be treated as a truth value, hence `flag` will be set to `true` always.

The correct way to do this is:

```
if (is_valid()) {
```

---

And, as an aside, it's not considered good form to compare boolean values such as with:

```
while (flag == false)
```

It's better to use something like:

```
while (! flag)
```

*especially* if you choose your variable names carefully:

```
int input_is_okay = 1;

void get_input (void) {
    while (input_is_okay) {
        printf ("please enter an odd number between 1 and 9\n");
        input_is_okay = (scanf ("%d", &input) == 1);
        input_is_okay = input_is_okay && is_valid (input);
    }
}
```

You'll notice I'm setting `input_is_okay` to false if the `scanf()` fails as well since that means you didn't enter a valid integer.